# Localization at a prime and direct limits

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1 \neq 0$ and let $P \subset R$ be a prime ideal. Apparently we have $$\varinjlim\limits_{f \in R \setminus P} R_f \cong R_P$$ where $R_f$ the the localization of $R$ at the set $\{1,f,f^2,\ldots\}$. Why is this the case?

edit 1: I'd like to use the construction of the direct limit and avoid the universal property.

edit 2: In case it's unclear, $R_P$ is the localization at the prime $P$ i.e. $R_P = (R \setminus P)^{-1}R$.

Comment: Where do you encounter difficulties? Everything is straight forward. (Ok you will have to do some calculations when you want to ignore the (essential!) universal properties.)

Comment: Two useful posts: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/751079/localization-of-a-module-as-direct-limit), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/664471/representing-localization-as-a-direct-limit).

Comment: See Proposition 2.14 in Ueno's _Algebraic Geometry 1_. It has a complete proof. Or Exercise 3.23 in Atiyah's _Introduction to Commutative Algebra_.

Comment: Could you please tell me where did you see the proof by using universal property?